# Python - How to know you are logged in with urllib2

Tags: python, authentication, request

When you would normally login to a website we can use urllib2.Request as so.

```
import urllib2, base64
req = urllib2.Request("http://www.facebook.com/")
base64string = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" % ("username", "password")).replace("\n", "")
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
requested = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

But how do we know if you are logged in or not? Because you could of just opened a URL of a wrong authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should look at requested.read() to see what the page you just fetched says. :) 
Also look at requested.info() for the headers the server sent.

And you should be doing this in a `try: ... except:` to catch errors. See docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html .

FWIW, the modern approach is to use the Requests module.

**EDIT**

Here's an excerpt from some code I wrote couple of years ago.

```
import urllib2

def post(url, params):    
    txdata = urllib.urlencode(params)
    try:
        # create a request object
        req = urllib2.Request(url, txdata)

        # and open it to return a handle on the url
        handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    except IOError, e:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'We failed to open "%s".' % url
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            print >>sys.stderr, 'We failed with error code - %s.' % e.code
        elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            print >>sys.stderr, "The error object has the following 'reason' attribute :"
            print >>sys.stderr, e.reason
            print >>sys.stderr, "This usually means the server doesn't exist,"
            print >>sys.stderr, "is down, or we don't have an internet connection."
        #raise SystemExit, 1
        raise
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Here are the headers of the page :\n%s\n' % handle.info()
        true_url = handle.geturl()
        print >>sys.stderr, "\nTrue URL = '%s'\n" % true_url

        return true_url
```

I hope that gives you a few ideas.

**EDIT 2**

To handle cookies, just do this before you create a request object:

```
    # build opener with HTTPCookieProcessor
    cookie_handler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Comment: I would like to use more effective techniques than using different modules :/

Comment: FWIW, I've only ever used urllib2 (and urllib) myself; I just mentioned Requests because it is very popular and apparently a _lot_ easier to use. But anyway, as I said above your program needs to do some exception handling and you should look at the response code etc in the headers that the server sends you, which you'll find in requested.info(). If you like, I'll paste some simple example code in my answer above.

Comment: I'd really like that yes please :)

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use *.info()* but I would try it 1 with a incorrect password and 1 with a correct password and the same data would print. But this may link into using an cookie module to store cookies in the info so thanks alot.

Comment: Cookies are easy peasy. :) I recommend you just play around attempting to open various websites, printing the headers you get sent, and trying to understand what it all means. Of course, don't try to log into places like bank websites that get upset by multiple attempts at unauthorised logins. :)